# How do I get a vuex store working globally with Typescript and SSR?

Tags: typescript, vuex, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I followed the basic example from this page

https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/store.html#class-based

I installed "vuex-module-decorators": "^0.17.0" as a dev dependency

I made a module ~/store/mymodule.ts

```
import { Module, VuexModule, Mutation } from 'vuex-module-decorators'

@Module({
  name: 'mymodule',
  stateFactory: true,
  namespaced: true,
})
class MyModule extends VuexModule {
  wheels = 2

  @Mutation
  incrWheels(extra) {
    this.wheels += extra
  }

  get axles() {
    return this.wheels / 2
  }
}
```

and put this in my index ~/store/index.ts

```
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import { initialiseStores } from '~/utils/store-accessor'

const initializer = (store: Store<any>) => initialiseStores(store)

export const plugins = [initializer]
export * from '~/utils/store-accessor'
```

But intellisense is telling me that '~/utils/store-accessor' cannot be found?

```
Cannot find module '~/utils/store-accessor' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

What am I missing? Will this work with SSR? And would I be able to access the store globally? And how would I access it globally?